Azure Stream Analytics get counts only if count has changed between windows
I'm trying to create a query in Azure Stream Analytics that each hour will give me number of events (grouped by some columns) in last 8 hours.
I'm using HoppingWindow(hour, 8, 1) in my GROUP BY clause and it gives me the results I need.
However, I would like to get only records where the count has increased compared to previous window to prevent multiple alerts related to the same number of events.
I'm not sure how I can achieve that, any advice?

You could use a sliding window instead off a hopping window.

Sliding windows, unlike tumbling or hopping windows, output events
only for points in time when the content of the window actually
changes.

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-window-functions
